# Getting "Multiple Target Patterns. Stop." error when attempting to build for Android with ndk-build

Tags: makefile, android-ndk, cygwin

I switched between using Cygwin and the ndk-7 `ndk-build` script and using the `ndk-build.cmd` script to build on Windows using the precompiled libraries. When I tried switching back to building from Cygwin again, I started receiving:

> *** multiple target patterns. Stop.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You should remove old "obj" folder.

Comment: Thank you so much !! You saved me from a painful bug. And "obj" folder is in your main folder for those who wonder.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Strange that even `ndk-build clean` doesn't take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your makefile has been saved with Windows/DOS line endings, not UNIX line endings.  When you see an error message that looks corrupted like that, that's usually why.

Answer (score 1):

I also meet the same problem, and I use eclipse. After I run the **eclipse project clean**, the problem disappear. I noticed that before the clean, there are two target armeabi and armeabi-v7a. The project clean cleans one of the folder and there is no problem with the ndk-build.

Answer (score 1):

I have hit this problem before. I changed the **make** to the newest version (manual downloaded), and fixed it.

Comment: I have this problem another time with android studio, while before with eclipse. It is not result from the make version, but the Android.mk did: LOCAL_PATH := $(abspath $(call my-dir)), here, try not add abspath: LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

Answer (score 0):

In proxmarx this did it for me `find -name obj | xargs rm`.  I couldn't work out which `obj` folder to delete so just dumped them all.  No idea what I'm doing obviously!